# res.download() callback function doesn't work properly

Tags: node.js, express

The callback function for `res.download()` is supposed to run when the download is finished. But sometimes it runs when download is still in progress. Is it a bug? or should I even rely on this callback function to know when a download is completed?

Comment: The callback function runs when the server has transferred the entire file to the client. But the client may run virus-scanning checks before it opens the downloaded file, so that it appears to you as if the download was still running. Is that perhaps what you observe?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Actually I'm using it for streaming video files. When I move seek bar in player to another part of movie, which means another range of the same file, the callback function executes instantly, while the video is still streaming.

Comment: Sounds interesting, can you share (the relevant part of) your code and also the requests which the seek bar generates?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen it's just a simple `res.download(filePath, fileName, function(){  })`, which there is a `console.log` in callback function, that shows if it's executed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you observed is the following:

- The video player makes a first request for your video file, with header `Range: bytes=0-`.
- Your server starts streaming, and the video player starts playing. It receives data from your server faster than it needs for playing (otherwise, the video would freeze).
- If you move the seek bar to a part of the video that the player has already received, it skips to there, without any impact on the ongoing request to your server, which still continues streaming.
- But if you move the seek bar to a part of the video that the player has *not yet* received, it aborts the ongoing request and makes a new request, with header `Range: bytes=1000000-` or so.
- The abortion of the *first* request causes the callback function to be invoked with the "Request abort" error as argument.
- The callback of the *second* request is not triggered yet. Rather, the *first* callback is made while the *second* streaming is still in progress. That's what you observe, but it's entirely OK.

Your callback function should treat such errors specially:

```js
res.download(filePath, fileName, function(err) {
  if (err) console.error(err);
  else console.log("Download completed");
});
```